# Is it necessary to make 50 diffrent classes for each state in the USA?

Tags: python, class, methods, tkinter

I'm working on a simple generator that spits out 1 random state in the USA.Followed by a city and zipcode from that state.I want my RNG to have at least 10 citys to choose from.(followed by the zip codes from that city)Do i really need to make 50 diffrent classes for each state and provide 10 methods for each class? Each method just outputs the text to the user. Nothing special. But I feel like there is something wrong here. I know there is an easier way this could be done with less lines of code. Am I wrong? Please look at the portion of my code if your confused.

How am I suppose to get only 1 output from 50 different classes? Can I make an array of all the classes then do `random.choice()` I don't want to write a ton of code for no reason so I only provided a `Newyork` class with 3 methods. But lets pretend I have 50 of these classes with 10 methods

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


class Newyork:

def bronx(self):
    bronx_zips = [10453, 10457, 10460, 10451, 10474]
    random_bronx_zips = random.choice(bronx_zips)
    new_bronx_zip = "Bronx NY,", random_bronx_zips
    return new_bronx_zip

def albany(self):
    albany_zips = [12084, 12201, 12202, 12203, 12204]
    random_albany_zips = random.choice(albany_zips)
    new_albany_zip = 'Albany NY,', random_albany_zips
    return new_albany_zip

def buffalo(self):
    buffalo_zips = [14201,14202, 14203, 14204, 14205]
    random_buffalo_zip = random.choice(buffalo_zips)
    new_buffalo_zip = 'Buffalo NY', random_buffalo_zip
    return new_buffalo_zip

newyork = Newyork()

def random_NY_output():
   NY_methods = [newyork.bronx(), newyork.albany(),newyork.buffalo()]
   random_ny_output = random.choice(NY_methods)
   return random_ny_output

def update_entry():
    locationstate_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    locationstate_entry.insert(0, random_NY_output())

button = tk.Button(root, text="Generate", command=update_entry, activebackground="blue")
```

As You can see, the `random_NY_output()` function Just spits out everything I need to know about the newyork class. Its gives me 1 random output. But like I said, I need only ONE output from 50 different classes. How can this be done?

Comment: No, you wouldn't have separate classes for each state, but neither should you have separate methods fur each city. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Im just trying generate 1 output. I want a random state. With a city and zipcode followed by it

Comment: This design is horrible (nothing personal). The purpose of a class is to serve as an abstract blueprint for concrete objects. What you want is `class State` and 50 instances of that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your posted example code, your requirement is to repeatedly provide a random `("City ST", zip)` tuple from a pre-defined set of such values.

This doesn't even need a single class, since it doesn't do any class things. (Here's a bonus video on not writing classes: [Stop Writing Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0).)

Just make a big list of tuples, and use `random.choice` (or `.shuffle` if that makes more sense for your overall application) to do the job:

```
_places = []
_places.extend((("Albany NY", zip) for zip in (12084, 12201, 12202, 12203, 12204))
_places.extend((("Bronx NY", zip) for zip in (10453, 10457, 10460, 10451, 10474))
_places.extend((("Buffalo NY", zip) for zip in (14201,14202, 14203, 14204, 14205))
# Many, many lines omitted...

def random_place():
    return random.choice(_places)

def update_entry():
    locationstate_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    locationstate_entry.insert(0, random_place())
```

Comment: I have a line like this 
`Newjersey.extend(("Syracuse1 NY", zip) for zip in [08732, 08735, 08751, 08753, 08754, 08755, 08756])` Its seem that its not working because all the zipcodes begin in a zero. Why am I getting an "invalid token" error

Comment: Nevermind.  I figured it out. I just converted the zip codes starting with 0 into there octal. Then just added `"0"` followed by a `+`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a different class for every state, make a dictionary that holds all of your information. Then you can generate your strings based on that and hard-code less information as well.

```
>>> import random
>>> states = {
...   'NY': {
...     'Albany': [12084, 12201, 12202, 12203, 12204],
...     'Bronx': [10453, 10457, 10460, 10451, 10474],
...     'Buffalo': [14201,14202, 14203, 14204, 14205]
...   }
... }
>>> state = random.choice(list(states.keys()))
>>> state
'NY'
>>> cities = states[state]
>>> cities
{'Albany': [12084, 12201, 12202, 12203, 12204], 'Bronx': [10453, 10457, 10460, 10451, 10474], 'Buffalo': [14201, 14202, 14203, 14204, 14205]}
>>> city = random.choice(list(cities.keys()))
>>> city
'Bronx'
>>> zips = cities[city]
>>> zips
[10453, 10457, 10460, 10451, 10474]
>>> zip_code = random.choice(zips)
>>> zip_code
10460
>>> city, state, zip_code
('Bronx', 'NY', 10460)
```

If it was my code, I would write a function for this (with a helper function):

```
>>> def choose_from(dictionary):
...     key = random.choice(list(dictionary.keys()))
...     return key, dictionary[key]
... 
>>> def random_city_state_zip():
...     state, cities = choose_from(states)
...     city, zip_codes = choose_from(cities)
...     zip_code = random.choice(zip_codes)
...     return state, city, zip_code
... 
>>> random_city_state_zip()
('NY', 'Albany', 12203)
>>> random_city_state_zip()
('NY', 'Bronx', 10457)
```

Comment: Why is this better than using a custom class?

Comment: I would still use a class at whatever level you're going to create and call it most, but I would perform the underlying logic this way to simplify your life. Instead of having to create a new function for every city, you can just get the needed information and have one shared function put the data together for you in the format you want it.

Comment: Oh, I just saw that you wanted a random state as well. So I would instead wrap this in a class that picks a random state, picks a random city from that state, and picks a random zip code from that state.

Comment: @BrettBeatty I want a random zip from the city. Not state

Comment: `city, Random state, zipcode` Example : Albany NY, 12084

Comment: Yeah, I meant city, not state. And you can use the information however you want. I included an example function that returns them as a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Since every state behaves the same as every other state, and every city behaves the same as every other city, the only real difference is the data unique to each city or state (names, zip codes).

You can create a single class which takes arguments that define the things unique to a state, such as the name and the abbreviation. The cities can be an attribute of the state which are either added before, after, or during the creation of the state.

For example:

```
new_york = State("New York", "NY")
new_york.add_city("Albany", zips=[12084, 12201, 12202, 12203, 12204])
new_york.add_city("Bronx", [0453, 10457, 10460, 10451, 10474])
```

or this:

```
albany = City("Albany", zips=[12084, 12201, 12202, 12203, 12204])
bronx = City("Bronx", zips=[0453, 10457, 10460, 10451, 10474])
new_york = State("New York", "NY", cities=[albany, bronx])
```

or combine them with this:

```
new_york = State("New York", "NY", cities = [
    City("Albany", zips=[12084, 12201, 12202, 12203, 12204]),
    City("Bronx", zips=[0453, 10457, 10460, 10451, 10474]),
])
```

You can then add your random choice methods in a generic way, because they just have to pull from `self.zips` for a city, or `self.cities` for a state. Or, you can iterate over every state, and/or every city within a state. It's all quite easy, and just depends on what you need to do.

The point being, create generic state and/or city classes, and generic methods that choose from the unique data for each instance.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing classes, use dictionaries:

```
zips = {
    'NY': {
        "Bronx NY":[10453, 10457, 10460, 10451, 10474],
        'Albany NY': [12084, 12201, 12202, 12203, 12204],
        'Buffalo NY': [14201,14202, 14203, 14204, 14205],
    },
}
location = random.choice(list(zips['NY'].keys()))
zip = random.choice(zips['NY'][location])
```

Comment: Why is this better than using a custom class?

Comment: And how does this solve the problem of having multiple states to choose from?